# Informação de uma API na sua aplicação web - Flask Python

Tags: python-3.x, aplicação-web, flask, python-requests

Sou iniciante em python e tô me aventurando no flask pois achei o aprendizado melhor do que Django.
Então desculpa  a minha ignorância no que vou pergunta ou se o meu código estiver errado, mais como eu faço  para pega informação de uma API de um site e joga numa tabela na minha aplicação?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

Tem que passar os dados como argumento.

```
return render_template('index.html', data=game())
```

Outra alternativa é usar AJAX.